# RuntimeException trying to run Drools examples

Tags: drools

I downloaded Drools 7.46.0.Final and extracted the contents to my local drive. When I try to run the examples from the Linux command line using the provided runExamples.sh script I'm getting the following exception. I've tried with Java 8 and Java 11 (the only versions I have installed). Does this really require Java 6 like the message recommends or is there some other problem here?

I'm new to Drools, so I'm afraid I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

UPDATE: interestingly I tried version 7.44.0.Final and that runs fine. So downloaded 7.45.0.Final and that one is broken too. So something changed between 7.44 and 7.45 that's causing this.

```
10:06:44.154 [main] INFO  o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.processKieService:129 - Cannot load service: org.kie.internal.process.CorrelationKeyFactory
10:06:44.157 [main] ERROR o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.processKieService:131 - Loading failed because There already exists an implementation for service org.drools.core.reteoo.KieComponentFactoryFactory with same priority 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.get(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:32)
    at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.get(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:23)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$Impl.getServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry.java:88)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$ServiceRegistryHolder.<clinit>(ServiceRegistry.java:47)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getInstance(ServiceRegistry.java:39)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:35)
    at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory$LazyHolder.<clinit>(KieServices.java:358)
    at org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory.get(KieServices.java:365)
    at org.kie.api.KieServices.get(KieServices.java:349)
    at org.drools.examples.DroolsExamplesApp.<init>(DroolsExamplesApp.java:59)
    at org.drools.examples.DroolsExamplesApp.main(DroolsExamplesApp.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to build kie service url = jar:file:/home/davek/apps/drools-distribution-7.46.0.Final/examples/binaries/drools-examples-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerConfs(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.lambda$getServices$1(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.getServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:81)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$Impl.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:60)
    at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier$LazyHolder.<clinit>(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:27)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There already exists an implementation for service org.drools.core.reteoo.KieComponentFactoryFactory with same priority 0
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl$PriorityMap.put(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:222)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.processKieService(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:124)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerConfs(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:101)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known issue that I fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/commit/d0e249f9c078b3e186ff1f0e2494e48913ed7571).
Upcoming Drools 7.47.0.Final (to be released next week) won't suffer of this.

Comment: That's great news! Thank you for the info. I'll continue working with 7.44.0 until then.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to version 8.16.0.Beta or newer resolved this for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).