# "Cannot load service: org.kie.internal.process.CorrelationKeyFactory" While trying to use Drools

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa, drools

I am getting this error when trying to use drools with Springboot, I've tried to change to different import versions but it does not seem to work. These are the dependencies I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.60.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>7.60.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
    <version>7.60.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>7.60.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
    <version>7.60.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.60.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I should mention that I'm completely new to drools so there's a possibility I'm getting dependencies that I shouldn't.

This is the line that refers to the error when launching spring:

```
2021-11-08 14:39:06.174  INFO 2808 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Cannot load service: org.kie.internal.process.CorrelationKeyFactory
```

And using the log in debug mode I get the following:

```
2021-11-08 16:01:39.559 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'kieFileSystem'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.559 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'kieFileSystem'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.559 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.559 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'droolsConfig'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.602 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Loading kie.conf from jar:file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-core/7.46.0.Final/drools-core-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2021-11-08 16:01:39.608 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.610 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.610 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Loading kie.conf from jar:file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-compiler/7.46.0.Final/drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2021-11-08 16:01:39.624 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.633 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.636 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.JaxbConfigurationFactoryServiceImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.638 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBaseUpdatersImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.638 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Loading kie.conf from jar:file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-mvel/7.46.0.Final/drools-mvel-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2021-11-08 16:01:39.813 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.mvel.MVELConstraintBuilder with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.818 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.mvel.MVELCoreComponentsBuilder with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.826 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.mvel.asm.ClassFieldAccessorFactory with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.875 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.mvel.asm.DefaultClassBuilderFactory with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.875 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Loading kie.conf from jar:file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-persistence-jpa/7.46.0.Final/drools-persistence-jpa-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2021-11-08 16:01:39.895 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.896  INFO 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Cannot load service: org.kie.internal.process.CorrelationKeyFactory
2021-11-08 16:01:39.896 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Loading kie.conf from jar:file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/.m2/repository/org/drools/drools-serialization-protobuf/7.46.0.Final/drools-serialization-protobuf-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2021-11-08 16:01:39.903 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.serialization.protobuf.MarshallerProviderImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.906 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.drools.serialization.protobuf.CompilationCacheProviderImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.907 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Loading kie.conf from jar:file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-internal/7.46.0.Final/kie-internal-7.46.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie.conf in classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93
2021-11-08 16:01:39.910 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.912 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.914 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.918 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Added Service org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl with priority 0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.918 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.persistence.jpa.KieStoreServices is implemented by org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl@2c846d55
2021-11-08 16:01:39.919 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService is implemented by org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl@735167e1
2021-11-08 16:01:39.919 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.runtime.beliefs.KieBeliefs is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl@67689c81
2021-11-08 16:01:39.919 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.ConstraintBuilder is implemented by org.drools.mvel.MVELConstraintBuilder@21a0795f
2021-11-08 16:01:39.919 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.core.base.FieldAccessorFactory is implemented by org.drools.mvel.asm.ClassFieldAccessorFactory@2ec156fb
2021-11-08 16:01:39.919 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBaseUpdaters is implemented by org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBaseUpdatersImpl@56d742ad
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.internal.builder.JaxbConfigurationFactoryService is implemented by org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.JaxbConfigurationFactoryServiceImpl@75784062
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl@5730b513
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.runtime.KieRuntimes is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl@73e25780
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.io.KieResources is implemented by org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl@1f4cb17b
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.core.base.CoreComponentsBuilder is implemented by org.drools.mvel.MVELCoreComponentsBuilder@280099a0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.core.factmodel.ClassBuilderFactory is implemented by org.drools.mvel.asm.DefaultClassBuilderFactory@7aca299e
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.concurrent.KieExecutors is implemented by org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl@1bf52f10
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.KieServices is implemented by org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl@6148827c
2021-11-08 16:01:39.920 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.CompilationCacheProvider is implemented by org.drools.serialization.protobuf.CompilationCacheProviderImpl@4da9da6c
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.marshalling.KieMarshallers is implemented by org.drools.serialization.protobuf.MarshallerProviderImpl@66048c9e
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.weaver.KieWeavers is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl@543ba2e1
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.persistence.jpa.KieStoreServices is implemented by org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl@2c846d55
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService is implemented by org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl@735167e1
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.runtime.beliefs.KieBeliefs is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieBeliefsImpl@67689c81
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.ConstraintBuilder is implemented by org.drools.mvel.MVELConstraintBuilder@21a0795f
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.core.base.FieldAccessorFactory is implemented by org.drools.mvel.asm.ClassFieldAccessorFactory@2ec156fb
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBaseUpdaters is implemented by org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBaseUpdatersImpl@56d742ad
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.internal.builder.JaxbConfigurationFactoryService is implemented by org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.JaxbConfigurationFactoryServiceImpl@75784062
2021-11-08 16:01:39.921 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieAssemblersImpl@5730b513
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.runtime.KieRuntimes is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieRuntimesImpl@73e25780
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.io.KieResources is implemented by org.drools.core.io.impl.ResourceFactoryServiceImpl@1f4cb17b
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.core.base.CoreComponentsBuilder is implemented by org.drools.mvel.MVELCoreComponentsBuilder@280099a0
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.core.factmodel.ClassBuilderFactory is implemented by org.drools.mvel.asm.DefaultClassBuilderFactory@7aca299e
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.concurrent.KieExecutors is implemented by org.drools.core.concurrent.ExecutorProviderImpl@1bf52f10
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.KieServices is implemented by org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl@6148827c
2021-11-08 16:01:39.923 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.CompilationCacheProvider is implemented by org.drools.serialization.protobuf.CompilationCacheProviderImpl@4da9da6c
2021-11-08 16:01:39.924 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.marshalling.KieMarshallers is implemented by org.drools.serialization.protobuf.MarshallerProviderImpl@66048c9e
2021-11-08 16:01:39.924 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.k.a.i.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl       : Service org.kie.api.internal.weaver.KieWeavers is implemented by org.kie.internal.services.KieWeaversImpl@543ba2e1
2021-11-08 16:01:39.943 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Resolved classpath location [rules/] to resources [URL [file:/C:/Users/LeonardoRP/Documents/GitHub/smart-place-catalog/smart-place-catalog-rs/target/classes/rules/]]
2021-11-08 16:01:39.943 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Looking for matching resources in directory tree [C:\Users\LeonardoRP\Documents\GitHub\smart-place-catalog\smart-place-catalog-rs\target\classes\rules]
2021-11-08 16:01:39.943 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Searching directory [C:\Users\LeonardoRP\Documents\GitHub\smart-place-catalog\smart-place-catalog-rs\target\classes\rules] for files matching pattern [C:/Users/LeonardoRP/Documents/GitHub/smart-place-catalog/smart-place-catalog-rs/target/classes/rules/**/*.*]
2021-11-08 16:01:39.944 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] .i.s.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver : Resolved location pattern [classpath*:rules/**/*.*] to resources [file [C:\Users\LeonardoRP\Documents\GitHub\smart-place-catalog\smart-place-catalog-rs\target\classes\rules\AttributeConfigRule.drl]]
2021-11-08 16:01:39.979 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'kieFileSystem' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2021-11-08 16:01:39.979 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.979 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.980 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'kieFileSystem'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.980 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'kieContainer'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.980 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'kieContainer'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.980 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.980 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'droolsConfig'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.984 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'kieFileSystem'
2021-11-08 16:01:39.984 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'kieContainer' via factory method to bean named 'kieFileSystem'
2021-11-08 16:01:40.000 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.d.c.k.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl   : KieModule was added: br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$1@443ac5b8
2021-11-08 16:01:40.991 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.d.c.k.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl   : KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0]
2021-11-08 16:01:40.993 DEBUG 14660 --- [           main] o.d.c.k.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl   : Cannot load a KieRepositoryScanner, using the DummyKieScanner
2021-11-08 16:01:41.011 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'kieContainer' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2021-11-08 16:01:41.011 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2021-11-08 16:01:41.011 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2021-11-08 16:01:41.013 TRACE 14660 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'kieContainer'
```

However, if I try to use a rule I get the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kieContainer' defined in class path resource [br/com/gwcloud/smartplace/catalog/DroolsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$1 cannot be cast to org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.Application.main(Application.java:25) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$1 cannot be cast to org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$1 cannot be cast to org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.InternalKieModule
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:188) ~[drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:176) ~[drools-compiler-7.46.0.Final.jar:7.46.0.Final]
    at br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig.kieContainer(DroolsConfig.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$611f5be2.CGLIB$kieContainer$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$611f5be2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be6112bb.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.DroolsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$611f5be2.kieContainer(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please include your full error including stack trace.

Comment: I'll include it in the description. I'm not able to put it here because its too long

Comment: There should be a stack trace immediately after that line. See this other question for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972049/runtimeexception-trying-to-run-drools-examples

Comment: Yes you can't use the rules if you can't instantiate the factory first. We need the stack trace from the load error, which should come immediately after the "cannot load service" log line, or else we really can't do much in terms of remote debugging.

Comment: The only line related to the error during the launch is the one in the description. After that, Spring launches normally as it would without any kie dependencies.

Comment: Something must be suppressing the stack traces, then. Try bumping up your logging to verbose/debug.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I put what I believe should be the part that refers to the error.